# "among others" at the end of a sentence

Tags: commas

The reading list includes Shakespeare, Chaucer and Milton, among others.

Is the comma correct before "among others"?

Comment: When "among others" is the last term, it is used without a comma. Check this out  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37772/the-usage-of-among-others

Comment: I would use a comma.  But this sort of thing is a judgment call.

Comment: Among others were the books by A, B and C. I like the books by A, B and C, among others. Yes, it takes a comma.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, the comma is fine.**

The "academic" section of the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/old/) includes 358 hits of the string "among others .", i.e. *among others* in sentence-final position. Of those, 302 instances are separated off with a comma. That shows that native American authors of formal texts accept, in fact strongly prefer, a comma in this context.

The following graphic gives the first 20 hits of the referenced corpus query:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

In [a comment, @vickyace wrote](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/330984/among-others-at-the-end-of-a-sentence/444310?noredirect=1#comment753900_330984):

> When "among others" is the last term, it is used without a comma.

For further reference, see [this post on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37772/the-usage-of-among-others).

A dictionary example without comma's may be found in [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/among-others):

> He is expected to be supported at the meeting by Dennis Skinner and Tony Benn among others.

Attribution for the example sentence:  "Definition of 'among Others'." Among Others Definition and Meaning | Collins English Dictionary. Accessed May 01, 2018. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/among-others.

Comment: Who is vickyace? In any case, all of this and that is misguided. Sorry.

Comment: @Lambie vickyace is a StackExchange user who wrote a comment on this question. Of note, vickyace had a source to cite for their assertion, and this answer includes that source as well as a couple others that support its position. If you have a contradictory source, feel free to write a competing answer.

Comment: There is no one on the page accessed  through the link in the answer called vickyace.

Comment: https://www.joh.cam.ac.uk/search-universal-grammar |Understanding why the principle was abandoned by one language family, but retained by the other, is the central objective of a new project which is being carried out by an international team of language scientists from the Universities of Cambridge and Oslo, among others.| That is one example, from a very lah-dee-dah source.

Comment: @JJJ Has one considered?? The link contains no comments by a vickyrace.

Comment: @JJJ My opinion, regardless of that CD sentence, is that the phrase "among others", when placed at the end of a sentence, should be preceded by a comma. I am sure the Queen of England would agree and she's the only one I care about.

Comment: @JJJ If there were another Queen of England, I'd fix my grammar before visiting her, her family members or her fellow royals, among others.

Comment: The only no-comma example that this answer provides involves two items, separated by an *and*. It is not obvious that this can be generalised to the cases in which *among others* follows a list of three or more items, themselves separated by commas.